# How to use php read modbus value?

Tags: php, tcp, modbus

I can connect to Modbus using PHP.

```
<?php

$fp = fsockopen("10.7.73.151", 502, $errno, $errstr, 3);
if(!$fp)
{
    printf("can\'t connect modbus tcp device\n");
    die();
}
else{
    printf("Link\n");
}   
?>
```

But I do not know how to read device values...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsTXu.jpg)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

FC3 functionality example

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Phpmodbus/ModbusMaster.php';

// Create Modbus object
$modbus = new ModbusMaster("192.192.15.51", "UDP");

try {
    // FC 3
    $recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(0, 12288, 6);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Print error information if any
    echo $modbus;
    echo $e;
    exit;
}

// Print status information
echo "</br>Status:</br>" . $modbus;

// Print read data
echo "</br>Data:</br>";
print_r($recData); 
echo "</br>";
?>
```